# Converting to decimal

Tags: c#, converters

I have a `BuyPopcorn` method that has a decimal parameter. It is supposed to return `Popcorn`.

```
public Popcorn BuyPopcorn(decimal payment)
        {
            Popcorn popcorn = this.AddMoney(payment);    
            return popcorn;
        }
```

That is what i have so far. Except I am getting an error saying cannot convert type `void` to `TheaterEngine.Popcorn.`

It is supposed to pass the payment to my `AddMoney` method and return `Popcorn` to the guest who bought it. How do I go about converting?

Here is my `AddMoney` method just in case it is needed. It does not return anything.

```
        /// Add the money
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="amountToAdd">amount added</param>
        public void AddMoney(decimal amountToAdd)
        {
            this.moneyBox.AddMoney(amountToAdd);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the `AddMoney` method does not return anything (void). It needs to return a `Popcorn` object for your code to work, as you can't assign `void` to a `Popcorn` reference.

`AddMoney` does nothing important (from what I can tell) that would prevent a `Popcorn` from being returned. Thus your method could simply be:

```
public Popcorn BuyPopcorn(decimal payment)
{
     AddMoney(payment);    
     return new Popcorn();
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thats what it was. I forgot to create a new popcorn. Rookie mistake! Thanks!

Comment: @Travis No problem. I'm guessing you'll need to do things like check the payment for enough money, etc. but this will get you going. Glad to help!